# How to connect MySql Database using SSH to Looker Studio?

Tags: mysql, database-connection, mysql-connector, looker-studio, ssh-tunnel

I have a Database that I am connected to using SSH connection. I have aal the things needed to connect to the database like host-IP, Port, Username, Password, SSH Host, SSH Port, SSH User and Private Key. I want to connect the database to my looker studio but i dont want to use any paid connectors.

I have tried different connectors but they all are either paid or give a one month trial, if I am connecting through a JDBC url then after Authenticating their are no tables shown in the database.

Comment: I connect mySQL to google sheets and bigquery and use the prebuild connectors into looker studio, but that because i have to link different datasets together. I did look at this as an option as well.https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/7020436#zippy=%2Cin-this-article